# Using the rubypython gem in ruby on rails, how do you call a python script from the lib folder?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rubypython

I know ruby pretty well, but I've never used python before.

There's this great [python script called colorific](https://github.com/99designs/colorific).
I've checked this script out in the lib folder in my rails app and installed the rubypython gem.

I was wondering how I now import this sciprt into the app, so far I've got this:

```
RubyPython.start # start the Python interpreter
test = RubyPython.import("#{Rails.root}/lib/colorific/setup.py")
RubyPython.stop # stop the Python interpreter
```

However it's throwing the error…

```
RubyPython::PythonError: ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

I was wondering how do I import this script and start using it's methods?

Comment: `Import by filename is not supported`. So `RubyPython.import` expects you to provide it with a Python dotted name to the module to be imported, not a path on your file system. Just like [the docs](http://rubypython.rubyforge.org/#basic-usage) suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> colorific is a command-line utility. It doesn't appear to provide an
>   API to import. I'd not use a Ruby-to-Python bridge here, just run the
>   tool using the Ruby equivalent of the Python subprocess module; as a
>   separate process.  (Martijin Pieters)

The colorific test suite itself imports colorific, and there is a file called setup.py, so colorific looks like a standard python module distribution.

```
test = RubyPython.import("#{Rails.root}/lib/colorific/setup.py")
```

The setup.py file in a python module distribution is for installing the module at a specific location in the filesystem.  Typically, you install a python module like this:

```
$ python setup.py install
```

Then you import the file into a python program like this:

```
import colorific
```

Or if you have a module name as a string, you can do the import like this:

```
import importlib
importlib.import_module('colorific')
```

However, python looks in specific directories for the modules you import.  The list of directories that python searches for the modules you import is given by sys.path:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

sys.path is a python list, and it can be modified.

I suggest you first build the colorific module in some directory: create an empty colorific directory somewhere, e.g. /Users/YourUserName/colorific, then cd into the directory that contains setup.py and do this:

```
$ python setup.py install --home=/Users/YourUserName/colorific
```

After the install, move the colorific directory into your rails app somewhere, e.g. /your_app/lib.

Then in RubyPython do this:

```
RubyPython.start # start the Python interpreter

sys = RubyPython.import("sys")
sys.path.append("#{Rails.root}/lib")

colorific = RubyPython.import('colorific')


RubyPython.stop
```

You might also want to print out sys.path to see where the rubypython gem is set up to look for modules.

====

When I tried:

```
$ python setup.py install --home=/Users/YourUserName/colorific
```

I got the error:

```
error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH
```

So I just installed colorific like I usually install a python module:

```
$ python setup.py install
```

which installs the module in the system dependent default directory, which on a Mac is:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

See here for other systems:

> http://docs.python.org/2/install/#how-installation-works

The colorific install created a directory in site-packages called:

```
colorific-0.2.1-py2.7.egg/
```

I moved that directory into my app's lib directory:

```
$ mv /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/colorific-0.2.1-py2.7.egg /Users/7stud/rails_projects/my_app/lib
```

Then I used the following code to import the module, and call a function in colorific:

```
RubyPython.start # start the Python interpreter

logger.debug "hello " + "world"

sys = RubyPython.import('sys')
logger.debug sys.path
sys.path.append("#{Rails.root}/lib/colorific-0.2.1-py2.7.egg/")

colorific = RubyPython.import('colorific')
logger.debug colorific.hex_to_rgb("#ffffff")

RubyPython.stop
```

I put that code in an action.  Here was the output in log/development.log:

```
hello world
[<Lots of paths here>, '/Users/7stud/rails_projects/test_postgres/lib/colorific-0.2.1-py2.7.egg/']
(255, 255, 255)
```

I found that RubyPython constantly crashed the `$ rails server` (WEBrick):

```
/Users/7stud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rubypython-0.6.3/lib/rubypython.rb:106: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   the more detail of.


<1000+ lines of traceback omitted>
```

And even though I could write this:

```
logger.debug "hello " + "world"
```

This would not work:

```
logger.debug "******" + colorific.hex_to_rgb("#ffffff")
```

nor this:

```
logger.debug "*********" + colorific.hex_to_rgb("#ffffff").rubify
```

As is typical for anything ruby, the docs for RubyPython are horrible.  However, in this case they found an equal match in the python colorific docs.

Comment: Ok, so I've got colorific imported with this code but how do you run the single line of code "echo myimage.png | colorific", does that have to go in a text file or can it go in the ruby module?

Comment: That's a _command line_ command.  You aren't using the command line. In your file (the one that imports colorific), you need to use ruby syntax e.g. `result = colorific.do_something()`

Comment: Thanks very much, this was all really helpful. I knew nothing about python, lol. Now I do :)

Comment: I went ahead and installed everything, and I tried to get it to work.  I found the syntax in RubyPython to be very confusing.  In any case, I am going to add what I did to get things to work to the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 1):

Your original code needed a few extra lines:

```
RubyPython.start # start the Python interpreter
sys = RubyPython.import("sys") # (add) method used to search for a directory
sys.path.append('./lib/colorific') # (add) execute search in directory
RubyPython.import("setup") # (add) call on setup.py in the directory
RubyPython.stop # stop the Python interpreter
```

I have a Ruby environment already setup as a template [here](https://github.com/Richard-Burd/rubypython-example-setup) that does what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I know Python pretty well, but I've hardly ever used Ruby...

There are several things wrong here:

- Python imports are done for *module names*; you are trying to import a filename instead.

  Normally, you'd add the directory to the `#{Rails.root}/lib` directory to the Python module search path (either with the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable or by manipulating the `sys.modules` list from Python code), but you are trying to import the *setup script* here.

  You'd run `python setup.py install` to install the library. Or, much better, use `pip` or `easy_install` to install the package for you.
- `colorific` is a command-line utility. It doesn't appear to provide an API to import. I'd not use a Ruby-to-Python bridge here, just run the tool using the Ruby equivalent of the Python `subprocess` module; as a separate process.